# How to capture user's input in react-select without selecting from option

Tags: reactjs, react-select

i am using react-select library and am wondering is there a way to capture's user input without selecting from the option. Basically if a user types in the field, i want to capture that input when it loses focus and not when selected from the option list. I tried using onBlur but it returns undefined as the value is never captured.

**important note:** The user doesn't click from the drop down options. basically types in the field and moves on to the next form field. But the value is always undefined.

Comment: You can try react-virtualized-select module for that. Take a look at https://dzone.com/articles/fast-searchable-dropdown-inputs-with-react

Comment: Check this react-select example in code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/2l99lry5p    this will help you what you want

Comment: @Think-Twice i took a look at the sandbox link you provided and this doesn't support what i need. It clears out the text after clicking out the field

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the react-select Creatable. They have [extensive documentation](https://react-select.com/creatable) for this.